# Password recovery using email

Tags: r, sqlite, shiny

I have a table called `users` with 3 columns (`username`, `password`, `email`). When a user forgets his password, he needs to insert his email to receive his password by email (password recovery).

I have two questions:

1. Why do I always get the message `User does not exist`?
2. In the second `observe`, is there a more efficient way to get `pass`
   and `msg`?

First:

```
observe({
    if (USER$Foget == TRUE){           # Foget is a flag
        if (!is.null(input$back)){     #back is a button to go back to the main page    
            if (input$back > 0){            
               output$page <- renderUI({               
               div(class="outer",do.call(bootstrapPage,c("",ui1())))       
               })
            } 
        }
    }
    if (USER$Foget == TRUE){
        if (!is.null(input$PassRecall)){     #PassRecall is a button to send the email
            if (input$PassRecall > 0){
                Mail_to <- isolate(input$email)
                query <- sprintf({"
                   SELECT password 
                    FROM users 
                    WHERE email='%s'"}, 
                    Mail_to, serialize=F) 
                    db   <- RSQLite::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="db.sqlite")
                userr <- RSQLite::dbGetQuery(db, query) 
                RSQLite::dbDisconnect(db)
                if ( length(userr$rowid)>=1 ) {
                    USER$existed <- TRUE
                }
            } 
        }
      print(ui)
    }})
```

Second:

```
observe({
    if (USER$Foget == TRUE) {
      if (!is.null(input$PassRecall)){  
         if (input$PassRecall > 0){     
           if(USER$existed == TRUE){
             Mail_from <- "estersilva1990@gmail.com"
             Mail_to <- isolate(input$email)
             subject <- "password recovery"
             pass <- unique(dbGetQuery(db,"SELECT password FROM users WHERE email=='Mail_to'"))
             msg <- "You password is: 'pass'"
             sendmail(Mail_from, Mail_to, subject, msg)
             showNotification("Please, Check your Email !", duration = 5, type = c("message"))                              
            }
          }
       }
    }
    if (USER$Foget == TRUE) {
        if (!is.null(input$PassRecall)){
            if (input$PassRecall > 0){
                if(USER$existed == FALSE){
                    showNotification("User does not exist !", duration = 5, type = c("error"))              
                }
            }
        }
    }})
```

Comment: Why are you storing the actual passwords?

Comment: @Dason never mind that, what about the "Bobby Tables" attacks? Plus we want one question per post here, and complete code examples for "Why doesn't this code work?" questions.

Comment: @Spacedman, I avoid putting the whole script since it is too long and I was not sure If it correct to make confusion putting all script. Anyway, I edited my Question.

Comment: We don't expect your whole code, just enough to reproduce the problem - anything else is just confusing. Your first problem probably isn't related to the password and email, for example, and must be related to the USER and input variable values. We can't run your code without sorting out a database.

Comment: `?shiny::isolate` doesn't suggest it has anything to do with sanitizing input, so [little Bobby Tables is alive and well](https://xkcd.com/327/) ...

Comment: @Spacedman, I edited the question and made a small database.

Comment: I don't know very much about what you're doing, but: you're using `if (length(userr$rowid)>=1 )` as your test that the user exists, but you seem to be selecting only `password`, so `userr` ends up being a data frame with a single column `password`, so `user$rowid` is NULL, which has length zero, so the user is deemed never to exist ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it as follow:

I mixed the first and second observe. Also, I changed `if ( length(userr$rowid)>=1 )` condition to `if(nrow(pass_retrived)>=1)`.

```
observe({
    if (USER$Foget == TRUE){
        if (!is.null(input$back)){
            if (input$back > 0){
               output$page <- renderUI({
               div(class="outer",do.call(bootstrapPage,c("",ui1())))
               })
            } 
        }
    }

    if (USER$Foget == TRUE){
        if (!is.null(input$PassRecall)){
            if (input$PassRecall > 0){
                Mail_to <- isolate(input$email)
                query <- sprintf({"
                   SELECT password 
                    FROM users 
                    WHERE email='%s'"}, 
                    Mail_to, serialize=F) 
                    db <- RSQLite::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="db.sqlite")
                pass_retrived <- RSQLite::dbGetQuery(db, query) 
                RSQLite::dbDisconnect(db)
                if(nrow(pass_retrived)>=1) {
                    Mail_from <- "YOUREMAIL"
                    subject <- "password recovery"
                    msg <- sprintf("Your password is %s.", pass_retrived)
                    send.mail(from = Mail_from, to = Mail_to, subject = subject, body = msg ,smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465,user.name="YOUREMAIL", passwd="PASSWORD", ssl=TRUE), authenticate = TRUE, send = TRUE)
                    showNotification("Please, Check your Email !", duration = 5, type = c("message"))
                }
                if(nrow(pass_retrived)==0) {
                    showNotification("User does not exist !", duration = 5, type = c("error"))
                }
            } 
        }
      print(ui)
    }
  })
```

Comment: Can you please tell us in brief, human-readable terms, what you changed?  Very few people are going to slog through the two different code chunks to find out ...

Comment: Sure @BenBolker. I mixed the first and second observe. Also, I changed 'if ( length(userr$rowid)>=1 )' condition to 'if(nrow(pass_retrived)>=1)'.